# To whom Action Delegate is refering in the given example?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

## Main Function ##

```
var action = new Action<School>((x1) => 
                { Console.WriteLine("Hello School");
                    x1.SchoolMethod(22);
                    x1.SchoolMethod2(33, "Second Method");
                });
                action.Invoke(new School());
```

## Class School ##

```
class School
    {
        public void SchoolMethod(int x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{x}");
        }
        public void SchoolMethod2(int x,string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"SchoolMethod2 {x} {str}");
        }
}
```

### Method which is created by the compiler because of lambda expression

```
private static void SpecialMethodToWhichActionRefers(School school)
        {
            school.SchoolMethod(13);
            school.SchoolMethod2(22,"Bob");
        }
```

I am learning about `Action` delegate. My first question is regarding "action" variable used in Main Function. Is it referring to the SpecialMethodToWhichActionRefers which is generated by the compiler? 
Another question I would like to ask is  what is the reason  of using Action with ClassName. During learning, I have mostly seen the examples of Action int,string  etc. When we refer this type of parameters to Action then it refers to the method which is having int and string parameters. I do not know the reason why we need to pass the ClassName to Action. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You provide class name because it's generic class and this is called **generic parameter**.

The reason behind it is to know what type of argument is passed into an action, so later you can use such method invoactions as `x1.SchoolMethod` defined in `School` class. Otherwise, compiler would complain about it with errors.

Read about [generic types](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNSc4cjSR-Q0ZPlEYcutCQWG7HAjSQ%3A1573816373495&ei=NYjOXYnxHYTLwALIyIPAAw&q=generic%20types%20C%23&oq=generic%20types%20C%23&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30l9.3915.4571..4701...0.2..0.86.225.3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i203.-45ais3Hr6Y&ved=0ahUKEwjJ34jviuzlAhWEJVAKHUjkADgQ4dUDCAs&uact=5).

Comment: Does the  action variable is referring to the  SpecialMethodToWhichActionRefers method?

Comment: @chaudhry No, why would it be? You'd neew to write something like `Action<School> action = SpecialMethodToWhichActionRefers;`

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer. ?

Comment: @chaudhry This code makes no sense, pleasy wirte full, compiling code and then post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action a2 = () => Third(50);
            a2.Invoke();
        }
        public static void Third(int x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Third invoked");
            int result;
            result = 3 + x;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        private static void SomeSpecialName()
        {
            Third(50);
        }
    }
```

Action a2 = () => Third(50);

Above line of code will create a new parameter less method, which executes the Third(50) method.Lets say the name of that parameterless method is **SomeSpecialName**. Basically, I just want to create analogy in this example and the question which I asked earlier. In this example a2 will refer to parameterless method that will execute Third(50). So with the same analogy, can we say that the variable "action" in the Main Method of the question also refers to a Method created by compiler. lets name it a "**SpecialMethodToWhichActionRefers**". This **SpecialMethodToWhichActionRefers** will take one parameter of type **School**.